# Collection with capacity and able to drop head/ drop oldest

Tags: c#, .net, queue, channel

I'm looking for a collection which creates a window of X elements, so that I can apply formulas on, e.g. Simple moving average, Exponential Moving average, etc.

Something like a queue with capacity of loopback period and when it gets full, then we drop head / drop oldest element, so we keep the most up to date ones.

Perhaps `Channels<T>` is suitable here? I pretty much added comments to the code.

```cs
var subResult = await _socketClient.SpotStreams.SubscribeToTradeUpdatesAsync(symbols, data =>
    {
        var trade = new Trade(data.Timestamp, data.Data.Symbol, data.Data.Price, data.Data.Quantity);

        // TODO: collection.Add(trade);
        // TODO: if (collection.Count == loopback) { signal = ... calcs ...; collection.Remove(oldest); };

        publisher.Publish(trade);
    }, stoppingToken);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel<T>` should work fine. If you create a bounded channel, you can specify [how the channel behaves when it is full](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

Pretty much any other collection you'd need to write yourself, which I have done in the pre-channels world. These days I'd just use a channel, though.